Why does my promise go from fulfilled to pending?
First my promise is fulfilled, then after I return it from a function it goes to pending when I log the status of the promise. Why is this?:
const createPromise = ()=> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const data = 'Something';
      if (data) {
        resolve(data);
      } else {
        reject('Failed to load data');
      }
    });
  };

  const showData = async () => {
    const data = createPromise(); // createPromise returns Promise<any>
    console.log(data); // PromiseState 'fulfilled'
    return data;
  };
  
let promise = showData();
console.log(promise); // PromiseState 'pending'

console.log('print_something');

Why would the promise go from fulfilled to pending?

async functions return a new promise. In your code, you have two promises: one returned by createPromise and the second one returned by showData function because it is an async function.

showData is never awaited nor accessed using .then

This should never really be an issue in real code because you should never really have "synchronous" promises like that. It's just an entirely constructed example that doesn't reflect reality. Moreover, even if you did happen to have a similar construct that produced a fulfulled promise, it's still a promise that you would .then() or await. And in either case, the code would wait a tick anyway, therefore nullifying the differences between getting a fulfilled promise and an pending one, since any continuation of the execution would happen later anyway.

When you write an async function, that function returns a brand new promise which (as long as you don't await it) will be in the pending state.
Promises that are immediately resolved as they are created is kind of a special case. Normally the assumption with async function is some async work will be done before it 'returns'.
So when working with an async function that eventually resolvesd, you can rely on this to be true:
const foo = someAsyncFunction(); // foo = pending promise.
await foo; // After this, foo will be resolved or rejected


"as long as you don't await it" sounds like you have to await it for the state to change. That isn't true - the promise settles by itself at some point.

"an async function returns a brand new promise which will be in the pending state" - only if the function contains an await or returns a thenable. Otherwise it'll return an already settled promise.

So what's happening when I return a promise from showData, which is supposed to return a promise. The promise is in the fulfilled state, what happens when I return it from showData()? What's returned to the variable from a call to showData()?

Thanks for sharing some of the exceptions @Bergi

@Zebrafish if you return a promise from inside the async function, then the 'outside promise' will resolve when that inside promise resolves. It gets chained much like multiple chained calls to .then()

@Evert The inside promise is already resolved, I logged it, it said fulfilled, therefore why isn't the outer one fulfilled too?

@Zebrafish Because it takes an extra tick to fulfill the outer one - just as if innerPromise.then(resolveOuter, rejectOuter) was called, and then is always asynchronous.

@Bergi So .then() always returns a (immediately at least) a pending promise? That's weird, I'm directly returning a promise, so it's not the same promise that's being returned?

@Zebrafish Of course it's not returning the same promise. An async function needs to immediately return a promise when called, even before its body completed, if there's any await expressions.

@Bergi Ahh, finally it's sunk in, thankyou.
